How do migrations using VS Code on Ubuntu
By running the following code on VS Code terminal. I had installed all the dependencies, dotnet SDK, dotnet runtime, and EF core. I am not running any DBMS like Sqllite / MSSQL server even on a docker container and get these errors for both sql providors.
    dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration --project API.csproj

I have got the following message after the first command
    dotnet build API.csproj

Trying to build the project
    sudo dotnet build API.csproj

Trying to build with sudo
**What should I do to solve this error ? **

Well, the message indicates a permission issue. So fix the permissions on the project directory or run the dotnet command elevated.

Just moved the project to the home directory and it runs and do migration.
